# Creating a plotly choropleth based on a custom .geojson

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, geojson

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I already tried to alter the code to my .geojson but it seems like i am doing something wrong.

geojson file is:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnSmith1790/bigdata/main/landkreise_simplify0.geo.json

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

polygons = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnSmith1790/bigdata/main/landkreise_simplify0.geo.json").json()



df = pd.DataFrame(
    #fips steht hier stand jetzt für die ID's der Landkreise in der Plot-Tabelle
    {"fips": range(1, 403, 1), "unemp": np.random.uniform(0.0, 501, 402)}
)

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=polygons,
    locations="fips",
    featureidkey="properties.AGS",
    color="unemp",
    color_continuous_scale="viridis",
    range_color=(0, 501),
    # scope="europe",
    labels={"unemp": "Gesamtscore"}
    
)   

fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.show()
```

Comment: What is wrong? Using your geojson, I have associated the user data fips with the ID_3 of the geojson so the map is displayed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that was totally my fault, i simply got the wrong (already working) code, i am so sorry. I Just updated the actual code with my problems in die original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AGS in the updated geojson is a string, but the user data is numeric. This is the reason why it is not displayed. By replacing the fips in the user data with AGS obtained from geojson, the map will be displayed. The user data needs to be consistent with the attribute data in geojson.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

polygons = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnSmith1790/bigdata/main/landkreise_simplify0.geo.json").json()

ags = []
for i in range(len(polygons['features'])):
    ags_name = polygons['features'][i]['properties']['AGS']
    ags.append(ags_name)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(
    #fips steht hier stand jetzt für die ID's der Landkreise in der Plot-Tabelle
    {"fips": ags, "unemp": np.random.uniform(0.0, 501, len(ags))}
)

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=polygons,
    locations="fips",
    featureidkey="properties.AGS",
    color="unemp",
    color_continuous_scale="viridis",
    range_color=(0, 501),
    # scope="europe",
    labels={"unemp": "Gesamtscore"}
)   

fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]